# Rails: Map array with values to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem. In my application I created the following migration for my model:

```
create_table(:calculation, primary_key: [:name, :value1]) do |t|
    t.string :name 
    t.bigint :value1
    t.decimal :value2
    t.decimal :value3
    t.decimal :value4
    t.timestamps
end
```

From the API that I am connecting to, I get a response that looks like this:

```
[
    [
        44812342,          // value1
        "723.21000000",    // value2
        "723.21000000",    // value3
        "0",               // UNNESSECARY VALUE (SKIP THIS ONE)
        "723.21000000",    // value4
    ],
    [
        44812342,          // value1
        "723.21000000",    // value2
        "723.21000000",    // value3
        "0",               // UNNESSECARY VALUE (SKIP THIS ONE)
        "723.21000000",    // value4
    ]
]
```

Now I want to write a job which at the end writes all the received calculations to my postgres DB using bulk insert. Performance is really important, so I thought I should map it first to rails models and then call the `insert_all` and pass the array with all the models. The problem I am having is that the result does not contain any hashes. I thought of using something like this:

```
name = 'MyName'
calculationModels = calculationArrays.map do |calculation|
    Calculation.new(
        name: name, 
        value1: calculation[0], 
        value2: calculation[1], 
        value3: calculation[2], 
        value4: calculation[4]
    )
end

Calculation.insert_all(calculationModels)
```

but I am not sure if this is fast to use, because in production it will do this for like over a million calculations, so my question is.. What is the fastest way to get these arrays into my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you response from the API looks like this:

```
nested_values = [
  [44812342, "723.21000000", "723.21000000", "0", "723.21000000"],
  [44812342, "723.21000000", "723.21000000", "0", "723.21000000"]
]
```

then you can just input records into your database like this:

```
nested_values.each do |values|
  Calculation.create!(
    name: 'A NAME',
    value1: values[0],
    value2: values[1],
    value3: values[2],
    value4: values[4],
  )
end
```

Or you can use `insert_all` like this:

```
Calculation.insert_all(
  nested_values.map { |values|
    { 
      name: 'A NAME',
      value1: values[0],
      value2: values[1],
      value3: values[2],
      value4: values[4] 
    }
  }
)
```

Note that you will need to set a `name` in both cases, because you defined that column to be part of the primary key.

Comment: I thought that I needed to use `insert_all` to prevent the millions of queries that gets send separated from each other to the database. Will this not be a problem when I do this for millions of calculations?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk. I am sorry, I missed the part with the huge number of records and the performance requirement. I updated my answer to address this requirement.

Comment: Thanks, I also found the package `activerecord-import` for efficient batch sql's. Do you got an opinion about that or any experience?

Comment: I think I used that gem before `insert_all` existed in a previous project. Worked well.

Comment: Is insert_all better or does it not make a difference?

Comment: `insert_all` will be much faster, but will take more memory. It depends on our use case. You might even need to break up a list array into batches, when the input and therefore the memory consumption is too high. But it will be faster, for sure.